# how to write a Python program to generate a list except for the first 5 elements

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my code below:

```
def printValues():
    l = list()
    for e in range(1, 21):
        l.append(e ** 2) 
    print(l[5:])

print(printValues)
```

Please let me know what's wrong with it as I receive this error `<function printValues at 0x000001CC16D728B8>`

Comment: Try to change `print(l[5:])` to `return(l[5:])`, otherwise the function returns `None` and add `()` in the function call to `print(printValues())`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. You are passing your function to the `print` function (`print(printValues)`) instead of invoking it by adding `()` to the end and then printing the result (`print(printValues())`).

In this case you don't need to call print outside the function because the function will already print. So this would work:

```py
def printValues():
    l = list()
    for e in range(1, 21):
        l.append(e ** 2) 
    print(l[5:])

# Call the function here
printValues()
```

**Side Note:** Your for loop only has to go from 6 to 20 (inclusive) so you could use the following for loop in your function:

```py
def printValues():
    l = list()
    for e in range(6, 21):
        l.append(e ** 2) 
    print(l)
```

Or even better you can use list comprehensions to do the following:

```py
def printValues():
    print([x ** 2 for x in range(6, 21)])
```

Just some tips ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `()` in your function call.
try this:

```
def printValues():
        l = list()
        for e in range(1, 21):
            l.append(e ** 2) 
        print(l[5:])

print(printValues())  #see () in the call.
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you here:

1. Your not actually getting an error. What you see printed there is the actual function as an object. Try `print(type(printValues))` and you'll will get `<class 'function'>` and then use as you would with printValues.
   Which you can assign to a variable as such: `my_function = printValues`.
2. To execute your function you need round brackets e.g. `printValues()`

In this case you have to options:

1. Instead of `print(l[5:])` do: `return l[5:]` and replace `print(printValues)` 
   with `print(printValues())`
2. Keep `print(l[5:])` in function and replace `print(printValues)` with `printValues()`